# how to horizontally center a floating div with images in it?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align my image gallery for ebay, and I can't have active content so I have to use it with HTML & CSS. I am having trouble getting the images to float left with eachother & stay horizontally center on the page. They seem to be left centered. I am stumped I tried a whole bunch of different ways, but with no luck so far. I have spent 3 hours on this issue trying other peoples solutions with no avail.

```css
div.gallery {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    }

    div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }

    div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .responsive {
    padding: 0 6px;
    float: left;
    width: 24.99999%;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .responsive {
        width: 49.99999%;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .responsive {
        width: 100%;
    }
    }

    .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<html>
      <div class="responsive">
        <div class="gallery">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://s20.postimg.org/eaz0ihd0d/usb3.png">
            <img src="https://s20.postimg.org/eaz0ihd0d/usb3.png" alt="image of bluetooth 4.0 usb adapter dongle" width="100%" height="auto">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clearfix">
      </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to centre elements when you float them. Here, I have made it into a `block` and gave `margin` to centre them.

```css
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  display: block;
  width: 24.99999%;
  margin: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://s20.postimg.org/eaz0ihd0d/usb3.png">
      <img src="https://s20.postimg.org/eaz0ihd0d/usb3.png" alt="image of 
bluetooth 4.0 usb adapter dongle" width="100%" height="auto">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, that did center it, but it takes away the responsiveness of the device scaling. I need the images to be side by side if screen size is big enough. As the screen size gets smaller I need them to start falling into a column. I hope that makes since. Thank you so much for your awesome and fast response!!!

Comment: @RickMorty Sure... That's totally fine. Just remove the `auto` when it's small. That's how the original answer was.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```css
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery center-block">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://s20.postimg.org/eaz0ihd0d/usb3.png">
      <img src="https://s20.postimg.org/eaz0ihd0d/usb3.png" alt="image of bluetooth 4.0 usb adapter dongle" width="100%" height="auto">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```